# How to group li element via using Drupal.behaviors?

Tags: 7, javascript

A newbie question here.

How can I select a range of li so I can moved them inside new element?

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

To be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="column1">
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="column2">
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So far I tried using Jquery:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.menu = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

    $('#navigation ul li.expanded').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'none');
    });

    var $lists = $('#navigation li.expanded ul.menu'); 

    // Loop through all target lists.
    $lists.each(function(i, e) {
      var $list = $(e);

      //These are temporary variables.
      var $new_list = $('<ul>');
      var $list_item, $sub_list, $sub_set;

      // The number of items per column.
      var per_column = 6;

      // Calculate the amount of columns needed.
      var n = Math.ceil($list.find('li').length / per_column);

      // Loop through all columns.
      for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // Creates the sub list for the current column.
        $sub_list = $('<ul>');

        // Gets the first set of list items from the original list and adds them to the sub list created above.
        $sub_set = $list.find('li').slice(0, per_column).appendTo($sub_list);

        // Creates a new list item and adds the sub list to it.
        $list_item = $('<li>').append($sub_list);

        // Add the newly created list item to the new list.
        $new_list.append($list_item);

        // Create a div with the class 'columnX' and wrap the sub list with it.
        $sub_list.wrap('<div class="column' + (i + 1) + '"></div>');
      }

      // Replace the original list with the new one.
      $list.html($new_list.html());
    }); 

  };
})(jQuery);
```

The above approach generates "[image]

But I'm having difficulty in manipulating elements via Jquery or JS. Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where is this menu visible? If you're showing this for regular visitors you should consider manipulating the structure with php due to a possible FOUC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be optimized but you should atleast get the gist of it :)

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQAde/2/
Revised fiddle from new spec can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQAde/3/

```
$(function() {
  // This is the list selector you want to manipulate.
  var $lists = $('.expanded .menu');

  // Loop through all target lists.
  $lists.each(function(i, e) {
    var $list = $(e);

    //These are temporary variables.
    var $new_list = $('<ul>');
    var $list_item, $sub_list, $sub_set;

    // The number of items per column.
    var per_column = 6;

    // Calculate the amount of columns needed.
    var n = Math.ceil($list.find('li').length / per_column);

    // Loop through all columns.
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Creates the sub list for the current column.
    $sub_list = $('<ul>');

    // Gets the first set of list items from the original list and adds them to the sub list created above.
    $sub_set = $list.find('li').slice(0, per_column).appendTo($sub_list);

    // Creates a new list item and adds the sub list to it.
    $list_item = $('<li>').append($sub_list);

    // Add the newly created list item to the new list.
    $new_list.append($list_item);

    // Create a div with the class 'columnX' and wrap the sub list with it.
    $sub_list.wrap('<div class="column' + (i + 1) + '"></div>');
    }

    // Replace the original list with the new one.
    $list.html($new_list.html());
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi hampusn..tried your script but it mixed all the subitems from other parent with submenu.

Comment: Here is my original markup - http://pastebin.com/EcibzDhY

Comment: And this is thew result of the above script - http://pastebin.com/XLmyciiE

Comment: You'll have to specify select only the list you want to manipulate. Try changing the `$('#target-list')` to `$('.menu .menu')`. You might also have to run that code for each sub menu instead. Can you show what result you expect from the original markup you linked to?

Comment: Hi hampusn...here how it should look like - http://pastebin.com/adbWxT7A

Comment: I've revised my code to work with your original markup. Is this what you're after? Now it will select all unsorted lists with the class `.menu` which resides in list items with the `.expanded` class.

Comment: Hi hampusn...thank you for your effort in helping me out. I update my post/question above with your code. However I'm getting syntax error. Please see the screenshot above. Thanks

Comment: I think you're closing the attach "method" improperly. From the looks you should try adding a `}` to close the row `attach: function (context, settings) {`

Comment: Hi hampusn...yay my bad...the script works liek a charm...really thanks man

Comment: Hi hampusn...what happen if the menu items is greater than 12. Let say 15 li's?

Comment: Then the three last will get in a third column, as it is now. If you only want even columns (with 8 and 7 in this case), I would have to modify the script a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure I understand what you are trying to do - I am assuming the html is some kind of Drupal menu you are trying to add some kind of dropdown/flyout action to?

I am not sure whether you want to be doing all this DOM manipulation on mouseover/mouseout either? At least I think that's what you are doing from looking at that code snippet.

Taking your html example at face value, this bit of javascript should do the job of splitting it out into 'columns':

```
var $list = $('ul'),
    $items = $('li', $list),
    column_counter = 1,
    $current_list,
    items_to_column=6;

$items.each(function(index,item){
  if (index%items_to_column==0){
    var new_column = $("<li><div class='column"+column_counter+"'><ul></ul></div></li>").appendTo($list);
    $current_list = $('ul', new_column);        
    column_counter ++;
  }
  $current_list.append( $(item).detach());
});
```

Comment: Hi Andrew...yeah this is a Drupal menu I would like to manipulate. I'm thinking if it is possible to manipulate then on load when the menu items are greater than 5, so I can avoid mouseenter/mouseout which is a bit expensive I guess.